# Как обновить JSON в mysql

Tags: mysql, json

Как обновить такое поле JSON. Конкретно нужно обновить все в массиве, свойство `food -> name`, а в `name` обновить массив, в массиве свойство `language` `ee` на `et`.

Версия `MySQL 5.7`

Полностью за меня делать не нужно, только направьте на правильный путь. Примерно хоть бы увидеть как это сделать.
Руками нету желание править.

Поле `info` хранит такое `JSON`

```
[  
   {  
      "food":{  
         "id":12,
         "category_id":17,
         "image":"uploads\/images\/menu_-FueLMDpu.jpg",
         "price":23,
         "price_discount":1,
         "start_discount":null,
         "end_discount":null,
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null,
         "deleted_at":null,
         "name":[  
            {  
               "id":461,
               "field":"name",
               "language":"ru",
               "value":"\u0431\u043b\u044e\u0434\u043e1"
            },
            {  
               "id":1116,
               "field":"name",
               "language":"ru",
               "value":"234234"
            },
            {  
               "id":1117,
               "field":"name",
               "language":"en",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "id":1118,
               "field":"name",
               "language":"ee",
               "value":""
            }
         ],
         "description":[  
            {  
               "id":462,
               "field":"description",
               "language":"ru",
               "value":"\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
            },
            {  
               "id":1119,
               "field":"description",
               "language":"ru",
               "value":"44"
            },
            {  
               "id":1120,
               "field":"description",
               "language":"en",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "id":1121,
               "field":"description",
               "language":"ee",
               "value":""
            }
         ]
      },
      "quantity":1,
      "sum":1
   }
]
```

Comment: Какая версия MySQL, поддерживает ли ваша версия функции для работы с json https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html  Собственно это и есть ответ - если функции есть, возьмите подходящую, если нет - это лучше не делать в MySQL

Comment: @Mike `mysql 5.7`

Comment: ну там написано, что в 5.7 они есть. так что пробуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   UPDATE <table_name> 
      SET info = REPLACE(info, '"language":"ee"', '"language":"et"')
```

Вместо `<table_name>` поставить имя таблицы.